# TCA foreign_table how select label for select:options

Tags: typo3

```
$temporaryColumns = array(
    'my_related_item' => array(
        'label' => 'Related s',
        'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'items' => [
            ],
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_some_domain_model_item',
            'MM' => 'tx_some_domain_model_mm',
            'itemsProcFunc' => 'my\ext\TCA\SelectProcFunc->prepareItems',
            'enableMultiSelectFilterTextfield' => true,
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
        ],
    ),
);
```

Should be posible seelct which filed from target entity i'd like use as label. But cant find this in documentation.

For example - by default i get in selectbox:option

```
{value = uid
label = title }
```

but i need

```
{value = uid
label = clear_name}
```

Update:

I found that to get custom label just in seelctbox i can't use

```
'ctrl' => [
    'label' => 'clear_name',
],
```

as this will change list globaly - but i need just in select box. So i tried other solution in my TCA

'itemsProcFunc' => 'TBF\TbfPackage\TCA\SelectProcFunc->prepareItems',

and in SelectProcFunc.php

```
namespace my\ext\TCA;
/**
 * Description of SelectProcFunc
 *
 * @author Oleg Karun
 */
class SelectProcFunc  {

    public function prepareItems(&$param) {
        debug($param);

        $newItems = [];
        foreach ($param['items'] as $item) {
            $newItem = [
                0 => $item->getUid(),
                1 => $item->getClearName()
            ];
            $newItems[] = $newItem;
        }
        //$param['items'] = $newItems;
        return $param;
    }

}
```

Problem my $param['items'] empty - i found same issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85622. Bug or i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For [`foreign_table`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Select.html#id91) it is always the [`label`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Ctrl/Index.html#label) of the foreign table that is used to render the list of available items. So if you want a different field, you will need to change that option.

Comment: Thx, i tried like 'label' => "clear_name", 'label' => 'clearName', 'label' = "tx_some_domain_model_item.clear_name" but no effect

Comment: looks like ctrl -> label  global settings with influence to table i need change label just in selectbox, seems i need custom itemsProcFunc method instead or in additional foreign_table

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `foreign_label` overrides the label set in `$GLOBALS['TCA'][<foreign_table>]['ctrl']['label']`

From the doc [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Properties/ForeignLabel.html)